# String matching technique(s) by converting to number?

Tags: string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have various length strings which are full of Base64 chars. Actualy they are audio recognition datas differs by song-to-song.

For easily comparing parts of those strings i divide them into 16-char sub-strings.  (which is about 1 second of a song) But in some cases, i just can't compare these ones head to head.. i should be measuring them.

For example comparison with '`hellohellohelloo`' and '`hallohellohelloo`' should get a closer value then '`hellohellohelloo`' and '`herehellohelloo`' comparison.

Is there any algorithm or theorical

---

**Edit:** Sorry, i am new here :) And i couldn't make myself clear. Here are some comments that will make me clear and proposes an idea.

**Comment 1:**

*Actually i know about Levenshtein distance, but the problem is every time i compare two strings i have to build comparison matrix and that makes searching process slow. If i can convert for example hello to 4444 and hallo to 4443 i can determine how close records i have for 'hello' by just indexing numerical values.*

**Comment 2:**

*Maybe i should determine a base constant-length string(s) and store distance values from them as the index values for string. It's just an idea?!*

Comment: Does your "audio recognition data" actually contain readable text?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that if your conversion to "text" is so good that you can pick out words, or similar, then yes, a simple levenshtein-distance implementation, or similar, would work. If the whole string differs because of conversion issues, like waveform slightly out of phase, which generates different sample points, then levenshtein would be useless. Can you post some actual data from your audio?

Comment: No, it is not text. It is just full of base64 chars.

Comment: 222222222hUggggUh222222hhUUhhh22222hhUggUhhhhhhh is for 3 seconds of audio for example.

Comment: Base64 is an encoding, what it encodes could be text or binary (although there would be little reason to base64 encode text). So if you decode the base64 what do you get?

Comment: Actually i know about Levenshtein distance, but the problem is every time i compare two strings i have to build comparison matrix and that makes searching process slow. If i can convert for example hello to 4444 and hallo to 4443 i can determine how close records i have for 'hello' by just indexing numerical values. I think i am a little bit more clear now. :)

Comment: I didn't said i am `Base64 encoding` i said, i am using `Base64 chars` have a little bit difference i think. :)

Comment: So you meant printable characters then

Comment: Splitting into blocks so you can precalculate values for "hello", "hallo" etc won't work if the blocks can get out of sync. Ie you end up with "llohe" vs "hallo"

Comment: Draemon: 

"So you meant printable characters then" Yeah :) That's right. And there is no sync problem because it works by iteration over 16char substrings of a long record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Levenshtein's distance will probably help you : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

It's usually pretty fast, and there are implementations in most modern languages too.

Comment: Actually i know about Levenshtein distance, but the problem is every time i compare two strings i have to build comparison matrix and that makes searching process slow. If i can convert for example hello to 4444 and hallo to 4443 i can determine how close records i have for 'hello' by just indexing numerical values. I think i am a little bit more clear now. :)

Comment: Maybe i should determine a base constant-length string(s) and store distance values from them as the index values for string. It's just an idea?!

Comment: I'm not an expert in that field, but I'm pretty sure there are other algorythms similar to Levenshtein's, possibly closer to what you're looking for.
The solution to your problem could also be in the combination of two algorythms...why not work with Levenshtein's, and add an analysis of the char-by-char distance (this method has a name but it doesn't come to mind right now ><).

For instance : "hello" vs "hally" would give something like :
h - h = 0
e - a = 4 (b, c, d, e)
l - l = 0
l - l = 0
o - y = 10  (p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y)

See whan I mean ?

Comment: StackOverflow should really have comments formatting...Sorry for the wall-of-text answer :/

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I think i should do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) might work for you. Also see the Wikipedia overview of [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance).